# Motorola Phone Tools equivalent for Linux

Tags: linux, software-rec, mobile-phone

Is there an equivalent software for [Motorola Phone tools](http://www.motorola.com/support/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=ac7549e8fc20f110VgnVCM1000008406b00aRCRD&vgnextchannel=25aae66506e9d110VgnVCM1000008406b00aRCRD) on Linux for reading data on the phone (sync,restore contacts etc) ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there isn't and there won't be one. Motorola has not announced nothing in this way and I don't expect that they do it.

Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [Wammu](http://wammu.eu). Check what features are supported in the [Gammu Phone Database](http://wammu.eu/phones/motorola/) & if you think that's fine try it out.